# Angular CLI 12.2 | Numerous modules not found after creating new project

Tags: node.js, angular

I started a new angular project by running `ng n myapp`. I've used `var unirest = require('unirest');` after a `npm i unirest`. My first issue was a

> TS2591: Cannot find name 'require'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try `npm i --save-dev @types/node` and then add 'node' to the types field in your tsconfig.

So I did the advices and the `require` worked. But after that, my project isn't working, a lot of modules are not found, including 'util', 'fs', 'path', 'http', 'assert', ...
Any help please ?

My configs are Angular CLI: 12.2.0, Node: 14.17.4, Npm: 6.14.14. Thank's !

Comment: You cannot use require with Angular Project, you need use `import` like this `import { ABC } from './abc.module'` something like this

Comment: `require` will work with Node projects

Comment: You are trying to import node.js module (server side) into an angular app (client side) - that won't work.

Comment: Thank's all for your reply. @AviadP. if unirest doesn't work for angular app, does another http module exists for it ?

Comment: Angular has everything you need to create an app with http and everything. It's one of the most popular front end frameworks. Please go over the tutorial and documentation at https://angular.io/docs - specifically about http: https://angular.io/guide/http

Answer (score 0):

In angular this is not how you can import the packages.
Below example given  with lodash package import in angular

npm install --save lodash

## This is the new bit here:

$ npm install --save-dev @types/lodash

Then, in your .ts file:

Either:

import * as _ from "lodash";
Or (as suggested by Vikash):

import _ from "lodash";

Comment: Thank's for your reply. I run the install command, and I tried to do the following `import * as unirest from 'unirest';` in my angular service, but it still doesn't work : "TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'unirest'.". As said @Aviad P. above, maybe the unirest module only works in server side project ?